# thrift use of sub-namespace in python

Tags: python, namespaces, thrift

I know that each thrift file is supposed to define a new namespace. But I am not sure what is true for sub namespaces and specifically how the python code generation handles them.

To illustrate my confusion point I will give a simple example

lets say we have the thrift definition bellow in `example.thrift`

```
namespace py schema

include "service.thrift"


union KeyQuality {
    1: service.QA service_qa
}

struct Key {
    1: required KeyId id
    2: required KeyQuality quality
}
```

and in another file `service.thift` we have

```
namespace py schema.service

struct QA {
    1: required string YES_NO
}
```

now if I generate the python code using `thrift -r --gen py example.thrift` I will get a python package named `schema` with another package in it named `service` (which is awesome) but the `schema.ttypes` will try to import a package named `schema.service` and it will fail.

It seems like `thrift` is handling the namespace hierarchy since it's placing the `service` package bellow the `schema` but it's not doing a good job when it comes to importing the packages.

If instead of `schema.service` I define the namespace of the second file as `service` then a separate package will be created on the same level as the package `schema` and the import will again fail because `schema.ttypes` will try to import `service`.

I feel like it doesn't make sense to have to install two different independent packages in order for this to work but it seems like this the direction that thrift points me to. What would you say that is the best way to deal with it?

Comment: Good point. I'd suggest to also consider asking that question on the [mailing list](https://thrift.apache.org/mailing).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to be quite straight-forward. Prefixing namespaces with the package name and having namespaces follow the package hierarchy solves the issue because then everything is in the right place and modules are correctly referencing each other starting from the root package.